# Total function does not compile

Tags: ms-access-2003

I am trying to provide a total of all outstanding voucher amounts. 
In one place I have this code:

```
=DSum("[Voucher_Balance]"|"tblVoucherInfo"|"[Patient_number] = " & [No])
```

I try to mimic this code at the end of the page but it gives an error.
'the expression you entered has invalid vertical bars'

Is there any way to fix this?  We want to show the total of voucher balance per each patient.
I have tried changing the 'Region and LAnguage' list separator on the PC to a comma but that has no effect.
 i tried changing the | to a comma, !, . - all to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove those bars:

```
=DSum("[Voucher_Balance]","tblVoucherInfo","[Patient_number] = " & [No] & "")
```

If that doesn't sum, your field names or table are misspelled, or no valid value for [No] is passed.